# Is it okay to continuously update the position of composables in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am creating a piano roll UI as shown before, and each note (colored rectangle) needs to move continuously as the song progresses, as a function of the time elapsed since the UI started. I want to make sure I do this efficiently.
[image]

This is a simplified version of the code I have so far, which works but seems to drop a few frames here and there.

```
val startTime by remember { mutableStateOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) }
var elapsedTime by remember { mutableStateOf<Long>(0) }

LaunchedEffect(elapsedTime) {
   elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
}

for (/* loops over every note that is currently visible */) {
   val posY = /* a function of elapsedTime */
            
   /* draw box with vertical offset = posY */
}
```

Is there a better way to animate all of the notes? This approach seems bad, as it is continuously recomposing, including recomposing every note. Also, would drawing the notes into a canvas be more efficient?

Comment: Another approach you can try is to apply an animation with a start and end y pos and let the system handle it.

Comment: @BilalNaeem One animation for all the notes, or individual animations for each? A single animation might work well, but I would have to set the animation to progress at a constant rate forever, until terminated. Is that possible? If I instead animated each note separately to go from the top of the screen to the bottom, then how can I be sure every note is perfectly in sync with each other? It feels kind of messy, but I might have to do it that way.

Comment: constant speed can be achieved https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77218423/in-jetpack-compose-can-i-configure-an-animation-to-run-with-a-constant-velocity/77220383#77220383. but individual blocks need to be animated

Comment: @CoreyCleasby individually for each note. So basically the first note should have a start delay of 0 and animation time of say 5 seconds. The second note should have a start delay of X (this is the time it takes for the first note to become fully visible at the top). All the other notes should follow the same pattern. I would also suggest to only create the note once it is actually required to reduce load. Initially you could create only 5 notes and pool each of these notes to be reused. Object pooling is something you can look into where you have a certain number of objects which are reused.